# Reduce Space between navigation drawer icon and menu text

Tags: android

i Am new in android, and using Android studio 3.6.3[image]

i am trying to reduce the space between the icon and text (Camera Icon and Home), in my previous example which i did on lower version of Android studio i used the  `<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_padding">10dp</dimen>`  It worked that time but not working right now. Will any one put me on right direction, what mistake i am making.